# Какие есть возможные проблемы при переходе с APK на Bundle?

Tags: android

Давно уже есть возможность вместо традиционного APK cобирать Bundle

Я хочу узнать у тех кто работает с `Bundle` какие есть подводные камни при переходе?

Я хочу предложить сделать этот переход у нас на фирме, как написано в документации, что все работает, просто теперь для каждого устройства собирается то что нужно именно ему. И как будто проблем не должно быть, но мне интересно узнать отзывы с реальных проэктов.

Comment: Особых проблем не замечено. 
Только с 1 проблемой столкнулись.
Мы используем `https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview`
И вот хеш который подходит для `apk` не подходит для билда собраного через `Bundle `

Comment: постою и тоже послушаю

Comment: marazmone Пожалуйста, дайте более подробный ответ. Как вы решили с хешем для Bundle?

Answer (score 4):

- Если вы до этого создавали и подписывали только APK, вам необходимо зарегистрироваться в Google Play App Signing, иначе при загрузки .aab получите ***ошибку*** пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Генерируйте App App Bundle:
  ***Build -> Generate Signed Bundle***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- **Важно!** Ставьте галочку напротив ***Export encrypted key for enrolling apps in Google Play App Singning***, в противном случае вам придется делать это через консоль из вашего keystore или скриптом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Далее в ***Google Play Console -> Управления релизом -> Подписки приложений***.

  Выбираем загрузить ключ используя Android Studio, мы экспортировали его на предыдущем шаге. Там
  будет дополнительный пункт "*Создать ключ загрузки*" с пометкой
  рекомендуется, можно его пропустить и сделать позже. Оставлю ссылку:
  [*Создать ключ загрузки*](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423#create) **"Готово"**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

***Проблемы:*** Продакшн более 350к активных пользователей на момент ответа. не было проблем с API гугла хотя используется многое из FireBase и auth, cloudmess, analytics, config, ML.

**Но 1 момент был** - версионирование. При второй публикации во время инкрементации, выдавал ошибку, что версия с таким бандлом существует, хотя это делал скрипт который отрабатывал уже сотни раз. Повторилось и на другом продукте.

Ответ: проблем нет, советую переходить, dynamic delivery выглядит хорошо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]